# PHP validation is not working

Tags: php, html

My php code is not working. It is showing wrong messages. For example if I fill the email address longer than 10 characters, then it still shows that my field is empty.

```
<?php
    $errors = array();

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name  = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
        $email = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));
        $ip    = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        if (strlen($email) > 10) {
            echo 'ok';  
        } 
        else {
            echo 'empty';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Check your html form. There might be a problem there. Plus. You are doing everything wrong as far as input sanitation goes. In simple terms, Don't use any function that starts with `mysql_`, learn/use mysql or PDO

Comment: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="detail"  autocapitalize="words" autocorrect="off">
<input type="text" id="f1" class="detail" name="email" autocapitalize="words" autocorrect="off" />
<input type="submit" value="Continue" class="csssubmit" name="submit"> everything is inside a form..

Comment: do `var_dump($_POST['email']);` before the `$name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to validate if the email address is 10 or under 10 -> error then u should use

```
if(strlen($email)<=10) {
echo 'ok';  
} else {
echo 'empty';
}
```

but there are other email validators that are better

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // invalid emailaddress
}
```

because what is my email is 1234567890abcdsed@mydomain.com then it will validate false but if thats my email adress then i have a problem

Comment: it should show ok if the email is 10 or under 10.. if its over 10 it should echo empty... pls do print_r($_POST); before name

Comment: pls show me the print_r results then i can say more

Comment: No problem.. check best practise for this because the overal of you code is not that proper.....